# unable to update application permission denied

Tags: linux, shell-script, debian-installer, updatedb, apt-mirror

Hi there i new to linux and I just enable Raid 10 as a result i can only connect through a putty session and not remote desktop, everything was working fine untill i followed this article

https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/build-a-raspberry-pi-nas

I have tried to enable the VNC server which was enabled previously and i have tried to insta xrdp again which i did previously

this is part of the error message I am getting

Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/raspbian.raspberrypi.org_raspbian_dists_buster_Release - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

Reading package lists... Done
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/raspbian.raspberrypi.org_raspbian_dists_buster_InRelease - PrepareFiles (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_buster_InRelease - PrepareFiles (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/raspbian.raspberrypi.org_raspbian_dists_buster_Release - PrepareFiles (13: Permission denied)
E: The repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_buster_Release - PrepareFiles (13: Permission denied)
E: The repository 'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)

Comment: I assume you are `root` or used `sudo` so you have the permissions. Then, it seems to be **I/O** errors. Try `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: I just tried and i get the message saying   For more details see mount(8).
pi@NAS:~ $ mount -o,
mount: only root can use "--options" option

Comment: Did you solve this?, I got into the same, installed octoprint distro, the files mentioned "/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/raspbian.raspberrypi.org_raspbian_dists_buster_Release", but has name "/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/raspbian.raspberrypi.org_raspbian_dists_buster_InRelease" but I don't see what the problem is.. And yes, using sudo, but getting messages that filesystem, is readonly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be **root** or use **sudo** commamd

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/root.md

e.g. instead of doing

`$ apt install xrdp`

you do

`$ sudo apt install xrdp`